# How do I write code in beamer for the system of linear equations?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

How to input the code in beamer to obtain the system of linear equations as shown in the screenshot?[image]

Comment: with help of `aligned` math environment. Please, show us what you try so far.

Comment: As illustrated e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538483/194703) in the second example, you can use `systeme`.

Comment: I tried the following code :\begin{equation}\left\{\begin{array}{c}    x_1=-c_{1,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{1,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{1n}x_n, \\    x_2=-c_{2,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{2,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{2n}x_n, \\    \vdots \\    x_r=-c_{r,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{r,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{rn}x_n, \\    x_{r+1}=x_{r+1}+0x_{r+2}+\cdots+0x_n, \\    x_{r+2}=0x_{r+1}+x_{r+2}+\cdots+0x_n, \\    \vdots \\    x_n=0x_{r+1}+0x_{r+2}+\cdots+x_n,\end{array}\right.\end{equation} .It did not work

Comment: It was an error “\divide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools for that such as `systeme`, arrays and `eqparbox`. Here is a very brute force method using phantoms.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A system of equation}
\[
\left\{\begin{aligned}
 x_1&=-c_{1,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{1,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{1n}x_n\;, \\ 
 x_2&=-c_{2,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{2,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{2n}x_n\;, \\ 
 \vdotswithin{x_{1}}& \vdotswithin{-c_{1,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{1,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{1n}x_n}\\ 
 x_r&=-c_{r,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{r,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{rn}x_n\;, \\ 
 x_{r+1}&=\hphantom{-c_{r,r+1}}x_{r+1}+\hphantom{c_{2,r+2}}\mathllap{0}x_{r+2}+\cdots+\hphantom{c_{rn}}\mathllap{0}x_n\;, \\
 x_{r+2}&=\hphantom{-c_{r,r+1}}\mathllap{0}x_{r+1}+\hphantom{c_{2,r+2}}x_{r+2}+\cdots+\hphantom{c_{rn}}\mathllap{0}x_n\;, \\ 
 \vdotswithin{x_{1}}& \vdotswithin{-c_{1,r+1}x_{r+1}-c_{1,r+2}x_{r+2}-\cdots-c_{1n}x_n}\\ 
 x_n&=\hphantom{-c_{r,r+1}}\mathllap{0}x_{r+1}+\hphantom{c_{2,r+2}}\mathllap{0}x_{r+2}+\cdots+\hphantom{c_{rn}}x_n\;.
\end{aligned}\right.\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cpy the code, it was still an error "\divide"

Comment: @mathbeginner Do you get the error if you (1) compile the full example, i.e. starting with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}` or (2) just the equation? In the first case there might be a serious issue in your TeX installation, and I recommend an update. In the second case, please provide a complete example that starts with  `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. `\divide` is a very basic TeX "command", and chances are that it got overwritten by something else.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{System of equations}
\[
\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    a & = 1 \\
    b & = 2 \\
    c & = 3
    \end{aligned}
\right.
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** now is time, that you provide in your question an MWE, which reproduce your problem or show where you suck in writing own solution. It is not fun write an answer from scratch.